# OpenCV is crashes with SIGSEGV on System.loadLibrary();

Tags: java, opencv, raspberry-pi, java-native-interface

I'am install OpenCV on my Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+ (Operation System: Raspbian). But on a `System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);` my code crashes with return code 
`Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)`

Python samples is working.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know `OpenCV` but it might be you have to recompile library that is loaded by your Java code.

Also, it's good to look for `hr*` file where you might find crash log.

Comment: I'am recompile library 3 times. But did not help